# how can I check if ipv6 is activated on a wireless router?

Tags: wireless-networking, router, ipv6

I have a wireless router and I would like to check if ipv6 is activated on the router.

I have searched in internet but unfortunately although I know networking theory and what is ipv6 I don't know how to apply it to real practice, so I would appreciate some *practical advice* about what I should do.

Comment: You would log into the router and see if it is.

Comment: How? ( as I said, I don't know anything about practical use of it- log in to router etc, I read it and don't know what does that mean)

Comment: What is that you’re trying to verify? Is it about clients connected to the router being able to access the IPv6 internet?

Comment: I am having a problem connecting some tuner for cable TV and in the troubleshooting it says "verify that your router is ipv6 enabled". (My internet setup uses a wireless router)

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?ei=_xxoXMuyNsvTjgT9u4GoCw&q=how+to+log+into+my+router&oq=how+to+log+into+my+router&gs_l=psy-ab.3.7.0i67j0l4j0i67l2j0l2j0i7i10i30.13065.13065..13346...0.0..0.97.97.1......0....1..gws-wiz.......0i71.7MQSs0bcuwE

Comment: Okay so by that they most likely mean the tuner (could you perhaps provide the make and model and perhaps a link to the troubleshooting list?) needs IPv6 connectivity. Just visit [test-ipv6.com](https://test-ipv6.com/) to find out whether IPv6 is working.

Comment: @Moab Thanks for the googling. Unfortunately it did not work :(. 192.168.0.1 has the connection time out. Through other means (below) I found out that apparently the router has not ipv6 activated so the next thing is how to activate it

Answer (score 1):

First of all I'm assuming that you're using a SOHO router inexpensive one's / home routers. All home routers / SOHO routers don't support Ipv6 directly yet to my knowledge but they can configured but that's another topic.

If you are using windows OS , go to Command prompt -> type

> ipconfig /all

In that you can find your Ipv6 address

Go to this website to check your Ipv6 address working or not

> http://test-ipv6.com/

Look Ipv6 is address we used for connecting internet like Ipv4 .There is no extra features.The only difference is it's so long & complicated. Even ISP's don't bother. Only >10% of the world upgraded to the IPv6 address.

Hope I resolved your query.
Please do point out if any misinformation in this

Comment: “All home routers / SOHO routers don't support Ipv6 directly yet to my knowledge” – maybe ten years ago. Today, support for IPv6 is present in the majority of routers.

Comment: Thanks for the very useful help!. I am running a mac. I went to that website and it indicated my router is not running ipv6. My router is 4 yo. So I guess my next question is how to activate ipv6 if possible.